# Re-do the ignoring of ".gitignore" file

Tags: git, gitignore

In a git repositry, I have ignored few files.
I have also ignored the `.gitignore` file.

Now the problem is when ever I checkout different branches and come back to the same branch (lets say bug-fix branch) I had to again ignore all the files. (I use SourceTree to select the files and ignore either by directory or by extension).

So when I tried changing that, `.gitignore` file in the repository doesn't contain `.gitignore` in it. And either the `exclude` file didn't have it (Actually its empty!). And there is no `.gitignore` file present in the user folder. How can I track the `.gitignore` file ?

**Update:**
Contents of .gitignore file in repository:

```
*.classpath
*.project
.settings/
```

Comment: You shouldn't "ignore" your `.gitignore` file. This fie should be committed and version controlled just like the rest of your code base.

Comment: Take a look at the relevant [github documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/), it states that: `"A .gitignore file should be committed into your repository, in order to share the ignore rules with any other users that clone the repository."`

Comment: @Lix I understood that lately. Now how can i track the 'gitignore' file?

Comment: You should remove the listing of the "ignore" file from your `.gitignore`. Or alternatively, just add another `.gitignore` file to your project and commit it. The file should be part of your code's repository.

Comment: My comments are also for you and also for  future visitors who might be facing a similar problem as you.

Comment: Did you commit your `.gitignore` file? Note that if your `.gitignore` file is different across branches, it will ignore different things according to your working tree.

Comment: @Lix No. I ignored it by using SourceTree. Select the file, right click and ignore!

Comment: That file should not be ignored. I'm not familiar with that SourceTree application you are working with though... Can you revert that ignore action from within the application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have also ignored the .gitignore file

Don't. I understand your `.gitignore` file does not include any exclude directive for itself, but ignoring the file through SourceTree means either your global gitignore config (in `~/` or `$HOME`) or your local `<repo>/.git/exclude` file (or, in your case, or a SourceTree-specific gitignore file) is modified,  to ignore the `.gitignore` itself.

To know which one, do a:

```
cd /path/to/my/repo
git check-ignore -v -- .gitignore
```